# Oracle RAC on AWS RDS Custom

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Ok, so this morning it seems that Oracle RAC shows up as an option when creating a RDS Custom. The only problem is that it doesn't show any custom engine versions and it seems it is required to have them. Now I have a couple of Oracle custom CEVs so what gives? If I click in and create a new CEV the only option is Oracle Enterprise Edition. Even if I click in and create it from here it still won't show up when I want to create the Oracle RAC. Is AWS just teasing us or what?

[image]

Comment: This option doesn't appear to be accessible right now.